# Reverse for 'product' not found. 'product' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, url, reverse

In `url.py` of list app

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^Products/$',views.product,name='Products'),
]
```

In `views.py` of list app

```
def product(request):
    return render(request,'list/product.html',all_dict)
```

In template in which tagging

```
<a class="level-top" href="{% url 'list:product' %}">
```

Comment: update your post and add main `urls.py` in project folder. maybe you are adding a prefix name before including urls of your app.

Answer (score 0):

In template it's need to be

```
<a class="level-top" href="{% url 'Products' %}">
```

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'Products' not found. 'Products' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: <a class="level-top" href="{% url 'Products' %}">

Comment: keep url in lower case

Comment: url is in lowercase

Answer (score 0):

You have not added namespace, but you are using `list:product` in url but you have not mentioned app name,

```
app_name = 'list'
urlpatterns = [
    path('products/',views.product,name='product'),
]
```

HTML

```
<a href="{% url 'list:product' %}"> product </a>
```